# Views/Templates returning incorrect information in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a view which is returning all products, not just filtered ones. Even if I removed the last line products =, the template still renders all database objects.

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'products'
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"
    products = Product.objects.filter(category__name="sundries")
```

This is my template logic:

```
                {% for product in products %}
                <tr>   
                    <td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
                    <p>Cooked with chicken and mutton cumin spices</p></td>
                    <td><p><strong>£ {{ product.price }}</strong></p></td>
                    <td class="options"><a href="#0"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

and Models.py

```
lass Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'products'
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_category(self): 
        category_name = self.request.GET.get('category', '')
        category = None
        if category_name: 
            try:
                category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
            except Category.DoesNotExist, Category.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                pass
        return category

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        category = self.get_category()
        if category:
            return queryset.filter(category=category).all()
        else:
            return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['info_you_want'] = 'info_you_want'
        kwargs['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        return super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

html

```
            {% for category in category_list%}
                <a href="{% url 'product_list' %}?category={{ category.id }}">
                    {{ category.name }}
                </a>
            {% endfor %}
```

the property you want set is `queryset` not `products`, for product with category mains ask url `'www.example.com/products/?category=mains'` ,for product with category sundries ask url `'www.example.com/products/?category=sundries'`

Comment: Thanks, and can I define multiple querysets and pass to the template - or do I have to create views for each category?

Comment: Can't define multiple queryset.What does  have to create views for each category mean?

Comment: say I have another category='mains'. How would I get that from the same view?

Comment: hi, you need override a method get_queryset and return it in your ProductListView

Comment: Any idea on how to pass info to template?

Comment: Could you show me how you would render a specific category on a django template (in html)?

Comment: thanks, but will I need a urls.py entry for it to work? All of the categories etc are all being rendered on the same HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

short way

```
from .models import Product

class ProductListView(ListView):
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.kwargs.get("category")
        if category:
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__iexact=category)
        else:
            queryset = Product.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

Remember you are working with Generic templates
and of course this is guide and you need make a littles changes in this version of code. (edited)

Comment: Thanks, how would I specify the category on the template?

Comment: generic templates return a "object_list", ex: yau have   {% for product in products %} so you could make that change and keep it generic   {% for product in object_list %}

Comment: and do not forget your import at the top file from .models import Product

Comment: What I meant was how do I get the template to return the specific category?